# Divide laravel table into 4 columns from a single foreach

Tags: php, laravel, css-tables

I have a foreach loop that has data.
I am using a foreach loop to echo the data out into a table.

```
@foreach($data as $key)
 <tr>
   <td>{{$key->option_name}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach()
```

This gives me a table with one column and 1 row of data. This table only has one data field and instead of one long list of data, i want it spread over 4 columns.

I would like to have 4 columns so the table looks nice and neat.

Please see attached example image.

How it is now
[image: CURRENT]

What i am trying to achieve, after the 4 columns if there is more data then it starts the next row with 4 columns.
[image: HOW I WANT IT]

Comment: Add an index to your foreach, then when `$index % 4 == 0`, close out the row and start a new one. You could also do this with CSS divs instead of a table, depending on your CSS framework.

Comment: Really rather unclear what you are saying here to begin with. _"This gives me a table with one column and 1 row of data."_ - so `$data` must have contained only one single element to begin with then ...? So what do you want to divide into four rows now?

Comment: Another option is to use [array_chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to break `$data` up into groups of 4, and loop through that for rows.

Comment: @aynber, is there any possible way you could provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of creating a new row and column for each data point, simply don't create a new row by putting the `tr` outside the loop. Assuming your `$data` is a collection, we can use the `chunk(size: 4)` method to create collections of specified size out of the original `$data`.

This way every `$size` items we create a new row with `$size` columns.

```php
@foreach($data->chunk(4) as $chunk)
  <tr>
    @foreach($chunk as $key)
      <td>{{$key->option_name}}</td>
    @endforeach()
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

If `$data` is an array we can use the `array_chunk` function instead.

Comment: there needs to be a max of 4 columns then it starts a new row

Answer (score 0):

This is expected. Your code basically performs the following:

```
FOR EVERY ITEM IN THIS ARRAY:
    MAKE A NEW TABLE ROW CONTAINING ONE COLUMN WITH THE OPTION NAME
```

Ideally, what you need is a collection of data with the fields you want to add in your table. For example:

```php
$data = collect([[
    'name' => 'John',
    'age' => 18,
    'eye_colour' => 'brown'
  ],
  ...]);

@foreach($data as $person)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $person->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $person->age }}</td>
        <td>{{ $person->eye_colour }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly your `$data` is ,
but this probably going to solve your problem

```
@if( (($loop->iteration-1)  % 4) == 0 )
```

the code above closes the row (tr) and starts a new row (tr) after each 4 columns

it could be used like the following code

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>header 1</th>
            <th>header 2</th>
            <th>header 3</th>
            <th>header 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            @foreach($data as $key)
                @if( (($loop->iteration-1)  % 4) == 0 )
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                @endif
                <td>{{$key}}</td>
            @endforeach()
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```